# EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal while creating a TextField value for a django model. (how to correctly concat strings)

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

this is the model i am creating:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notifications")
    text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The "text" field is giving me issues. This is how i am trying to create an instance:

```
Notification.objects.create(user=instance.post.owner, text=instance.user.username + ' liked your post')
```

"instance.user.username" is a CharField. What is the correct way of adding that to a string?

this is the complete traceback i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abhigya/Documents/WEB-DEV/iiitu/iiitu/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include("events.urls")),
  File "/home/abhigya/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abhigya/Documents/WEB-DEV/iiitu/events/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/abhigya/Documents/WEB-DEV/iiitu/events/views.py", line 583
    Notification.objects.create(user=instance.post.owner, text=instance.user.username + ' liked your post')
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Comment: I don't see any triple quoted strings in your question as the title would indicate... Aside from the potential typo `instanse` I don't see anything wrong. Please [edit] and add the _full_ traceback of the error to your question and make sure your given example is a [mre].

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i added the complete traceback. I believe the minimal reproducible problem is provided. The Error is still present even if i just use a single string, i.e.                text=' liked your post'                                                                                                            instead of text=instance.user.username + ' liked your post' .

Comment: The example is not reproducible at all as I said, the error speaks about a "triple-quoted string" but you don't show it in the example. I can say even if you remove the line `Notification.objects.create(user=instance.post.owner, text=instance.user.username + ' liked your post')` completely you would ***still*** get the error. You likely have something like `"""` or `'''` in your code somewhere and never close it...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat oh, ok i got it. I had previously used """ because i wanted to include " character in my string. But that was not shown in the error message that's why i got confused. I realize that was a foolish mistake. How do i include " character in a string?

Comment: 1) escape the quote using a backslash `"\""` 2) Put the quote in another type of quotes: `'"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
text = models.TextField()
```

To

```
text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

You not define the length of the field

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#textfield the `max_length` really doesn't matter for a `TextField`...